# create my own framework in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift2, xcode7

I used to create my own framework in xcode 6.4 by creating a cocoatouch framework , build it and after that I create a new swift project and I past the framework created (like shown in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cPaa3FrRg )

the problem is now in xcode 7.0 , when I try to past the framework created in a new project , I got I compiling error saying that the framework is not found  (linker command failed with exit code 1 ) 
what is the solution in this situation ?

Comment: Is the framework written in Swift you likely need to convert it to Swift 2.0. Can you compile the framework separately in Xcode 7?

Comment: yes , I did it ,  I created a sample class that display a message and I compiled it separately and it worked , the problem is just copying the framework in a new swift project